# Quickly detecting identical nodes which are siblings to an ancestor

Tags: algorithm, optimization, language-agnostic, tree, tree-traversal

> I am trying to find a fast algorithm to identify couples of nodes (A,
>   B) that contains the same data and that are positioned on a tree in
>   such way that **a node A has as an ancestor the node B OR B is the
>   sibling of an ancestor of A**.

Take for example the following tree, in which the colour identify the content:

[image: Example tree]

- **`n6` and `n1` are a match** as `n1` is an ancestor of `n6`.
- **`n5` and `n3` are a match** as `n3` is the sibling to `n2`, which is an ancestor to `n5`.
- **`n3` and `n7` are a match** for the same reason.
- **`n5` and `n7` are NOT a match** as `n7` is neither an ancestor of `n5`, nor a sibling to one of `n5`'s ancestors.
- **`n2` and `n4` are NOT a match** for the same reason.

The naïve implementation of a "rule checker" is trivial, but it requires to traverse the tree multiple times (once for every node being checked), however I have the feeling that I can leverage two special properties of my tree to implement some better solution. The two properties in question are:

- **I can get a flat list of all the nodes with the same content** (in the example above I would get: `(n5, n3, n7)`, `(n1, n6)`, `(n2, n4)`.
- **Each of my nodes stores a reference to both its parent and all of its children** (this property can be exploited recursively, like a linked list).

...but despite my conviction that there must be an quick way to find the matching nodes, I so far failed to find it.

I am currently working in python, but pseudocode or examples in other not too exoteric languages are welcomed too.

Comment: for the person voting to close, the question is: "what is a fast algorithm for finding nodes A and B that contain the same data where either A is either a descendant of B or a descendant of one of B's siblings?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the solution. The solution takes O(1) to answer each query after a pre-calculation of dfs-visiting-time costs O(n).

the dfs looks like:

```python
nowtime=0
def dfs(node):
    global nowtime
    nowtime+=1
    node.come_time=nowtime
    for i in node.sons:
        dfs(i)
    nowtime+=1
    node.leave_time=nowtime
dfs(root)
```

Then, we have :

B is an ancestor of A , if and only if we have

**B.come_time < A.come_time** and **B.leave_time > A.leave_time**

I think it's true that:

A is a descendant of B's siblings, **if and only if** A is a descendant of B's direct father. And (thanks to @mac) A is not one of B's siblings. And also A is not a descendant of B.

so we can check :

**B.fa.come_time < A.come_time** and **B.fa.leave_time > A.leave_time**

and

**B.fa != A.fa**

To sum up, to answer a query we have :

```python
def check(A,B):
    if B.come_time<A.come_time and B.leave_time>A.leave_time:
        return True
    if B.has_father() and A.has_father():
        if A.fa==B.fa:
            return False
        if B.fa.come_time<A.come_time and B.fa.leave_time>A.leave_time:
            return True
    return False
```

The key idea in this solution is to use the visiting time in a dfs() to check if a node B is another node A's ancestor. the **[come_time, leave_time]** interval is exactly the time-interval that a node is kept in the stack. It's easy to verify that in a dfs procedure, an ancestor's visiting time-interval will contain the time-intervals of all it's descendants, since it's always in the stack while the dfs() is visiting it's descendants.

Added:

We can prove that:

> A is a descendant of B's siblings, **if and only if** A is a
>   descendant of B's direct father. And (thanks to @mac) A is not one of
>   B's siblings. And also A is not a descendant of B.

since:

If A is a descendant of B's direct father, then A is in the sub-tree rooted at B.fa
The sub-tree contains and only contains:

1. B.fa
2. B
3. B's siblings
4. descendants of B
5. descendants of B's siblings

So, if A is not 1, not 2, not in 3, not in 4, then A must be in 5.

And if A is not a descendant of B's direct father, then A is not in the sub-tree. it's clear that A can never be a descendant of B's siblings, since all the siblings of B are in the sub-tree.

Comment: It seems a clever idea, smart and +1 (for now!). One thing that I can already spot (but easily fixable) is that `A is a descendant of B's siblings, if and only if A is a descendant of B's direct father` will return false positives for `A=n2`, `B=n4`.

Comment: @mac fixed the special case, and added more explanation.

Comment: and it's so difficult to get an answer accepted on stackoverflow .. :(

Comment: it's not accepted only because I am still working on its implementation! Once code passes test you will get your glory! :)

Comment: The come/leave time appears to be a riff on nested sets http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model. Is there a reason to use time as opposed to an incrementing counter for that purpose?

Comment: @orangepips - `Time` is already a counter in the example. It's the name variable that is a misnomer...